# Unable to run python with sublime text

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I have try to run python with sublime text and the following error message appear on my screen when I run the program.

Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.
[Finished in 277ms].

Please advise how to fix the problem.

Comment: The error is telling you that Windows can't find Python; did you install Python on your system?

Comment: Hi OdatNurd, Please note I have install Python on my system, I am able to check via command prompt and Python is install on my system.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Check python is in path

Them try `ctrl + B` on sublime text

Or you can start python file via python app in terminal `python path_to_file.py`

Comment: Hi Chvmq, Many thanks for your instructions above. I still have the same problem as stated above.